# "What is a good alternative to X" posts - why are they sometimes off-topic and sometimes not?

Tags: discussion, scope

Consider

[Hashtable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133569/hashtable-in-c)

and

[C++ - a better alternative to STL's map and Boost's unordered_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785203/c-a-better-alternative-to-stls-map-and-boosts-unordered-map)

They're very similar questions in many respects - the one-sentence version is the same - except one is for ordered maps and the other for unordered maps. So why is off-topic and the other not so?

Comment: This is a really deep question the more you think about it. What does "better" mean? That can be subjective and I can see why there would be backlash against the question. At the same time, the question is valid in its own right, and there must be some forum where this type of question can be legitimately asked. I'd like to know where that forum is, because I have questions of that nature too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first question was posted in 2008, the second one in 2014. Stack Overflow's rules have been changed over the time, so a question like that was still on-topic a few years ago, but now it isn't anymore.

Comment: ... and should this not be closed as off-topic now? I mean, it's not deleted and the votes don't go away.

Comment: @einpoklum These questions can be closed now, yes.

Comment: To be more specific, we learned they don't work for us. The problem is that it's not clear what the askers actual problem is, and one needs good knowledge of the presented thing to even have a chance of guessing right.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I wasn't asking about why the policy changed, but thanks.